# Xpath query for HTML - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this snippet of HTML inside a `<BODY>` that I'm trying to select with scrapy:

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="social clearfix">
        <div class="profile profile-nano pull-left">
            <a href="https://xxx" title="xxx"> <img src="/xxx" class="avatar" height="48" width="48" title="xxx" alt="xxx"> </a> 
        </div>
        <p class="byline pull-left text-left"><strong>BY <a class="text-uppercase" href="https://xxx">xxx</a><br />
            September 07, 2015</strong> </p>
```

This is the xpath selector I'm using to get the date:

```
response.selector.xpath('//p/@byline/text()')
```

Which returns a null result.

What am I doing wrong in my xpath selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//p/@byline/text()` would match nothing since here you are basically trying to get the `byline` attribute from a `p` element and the provided `p` element does not have a `byline` attribute.

You can get the following sibling of the `a` element inside the `div` element having `byline` class:

```
In [1]: response.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'byline')]//a/following-sibling::text()").extract()[0].strip()
Out[1]: u'September 07, 2015'
```

Alternatively, you may get all the text nodes from the appropriate `p` element and filter out the desired one by checking it with a regular expression pattern via [`re:test()` function](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions):

```
In [2]: response.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'byline')]//text()[re:test(., '\w+ \d{2}, \d{4}')]").extract()[0].strip()
Out[2]: u'September 07, 2015'
```